# Implication and Precautions for Azure AD Migration from On Prem AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune, azure-security

One of my customers would like to know what are all the implications and what all precautions one needs to take before migrating all their identities to Azure and use Azure AD as the main AD. Any kind of documentation on this would be really helpful.
 I would also need to show the various workflows how the authentication for a user accessing a particular resource would work using Azure AD and use of various technologies like PIM, CA,Intune etc. Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad and not well defined. Internet search for documentation on how to migrate. The number of issues that you need to consider depends on your environment, which is not clearly stated in your question.

Comment: Well to add to my question, my customer has setup Azure AD Connect sync and using PHS for authentication at the moment. They would like to get rid of the On Prem Domain controllers and use Azure AD as the main identity store both for On Prem as well as born in the cloud users going forward. So how this cutover can be done since there is no direct migration service offered by microsoft to migrate on prem ad to azure AD. Will setting up of an Azure AD DS environment help or setting up an IaaS domain controller in Azure which is replicated from the On Prem DC

Comment: Azure Active Directory is not a replacement for on-prem Active Directory.